# Blank Response for checking domain availability in resellerclub api request

Tags: php

I am trying to check domain availability from reseller club API. When I try it will show a blank page. No any errors or response showed

Here is my code

```
$url = 'https://test.httpapi.com//api/domains/available.json?auth-userid=MYID&api-key=MY_API_KEY&domain-name=shivaywebsolutions&tlds=com&tlds=net&suggest-alternative=true';



    //if ($data) $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $apidata = curl_exec($curl);

    $apidata_json = json_decode($apidata, TRUE);
    return $apidata_json;
```

[image: here is my screenshot]

Comment: You need to show us _all_ relevant code including your debug info. What do you do after you return `$apidata_json`? Checked your servers error log? Tried `var_dump($apidata)` to check what the response actually returns?

Comment: You're not echoing anything? Please write the full code.

Comment: I run it on localhost not on serve.

Comment: and i print the response also

Comment: It's your web server that logs the errors, which you still use when running localhost, unless you're using PHP's internal web server? _"and i print the response also"_ - You need to show us that code too. As mentioned, show _all_ relevant code. Also update the question to include the actual api-response too.

Comment: there is no error log generated for this in my server

Comment: Well, you've still not posted all the code or any debug data, even though we've asked several times. I'm out.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment the return data and try to echo it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).